# Знак "информированный" решил захватить отданные голоса пользователя!

Tags: дефект, дизайн, знаки, профиль-участника

Зашёл в профиль какого-то участника. И увидел, что следующий знак (в данном случае это "Информированный")  решил захватить отданные голоса:

[image: проблема]

Как вариант, можно сделать так, чтобы
недавно полученный знак располагался выше, чем следующий.

**Дополнение:**
Этот баг происходит только если следующий знак - "Информированный". С другими знаками всё нормально:

[image: с другими знаками всё нормально]

**Снова дополнение**: [вот пример профиля с багом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/547316/user2145125?tab=topactivity).
Или [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/547125/%d0%91%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba?tab=topactivity). Или [этот профиль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/547393/mrzodvig?tab=topactivity) (смотрите страницу "активность").

**И опять дополнение:** ОС - `Windows 7`, браузер - `google chrome`, размер окна - полноэкраный режим.

Comment: это надо писать [сюды](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ например, [этот профиль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/547316/user2145125?tab=topactivity)

Comment: Нужно указать ОС, браузер, размеры окна. Потому как у меня на iPad проблема [не проявляется](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lG7b.jpg).

Comment: размер окна в пикселях всё же. полноэкранный — не универсальная характеристика. Ну и версия браузера, наличие доп.расширений стоит указать.

Comment: win11, хром  111.0.5563.65, при ширине экрана более 1228 пикселей и более. Если делать ширину меньше, то нормально уезжает плашка вниз.